# Best practice to have the same view and store multiple times in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, parameters, store

I would like to have different instances of the same view with different stores at the same time in an ExtJS application. At the moment i ceate multiple instances of the same view (Ext.view.View) in the viewport.

But what is the best practice to have a different store in every view? Every example that i found uses a Store-ID in the view that was created using the stores-Config of the controller. But this would use the same store for every view.

At the moment i figured the following possible solutions:

1. Create an own store class for every view instance. Add all stores to controller and use different Store-ID for every view instance.
2. Do not use stores of controller at all and create a new store in the initComponent of the view manually passing different parameters to each instance of the store.
3. Do not use stores of controller at all and create a new store in the initComponent of the view manually. Then use load to load the store manually using different parameters for each instance of the store.

Is any of this solutions the best practice or should it be done differently?

Comment: Downvote without comment is so useless...

Comment: It's a fair question, I don't see why this was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks. Btw i decided for solution 3 for the time until a better solution was posted.

Comment: One of the problems I can think is the extra code to destroy those stores when you destroy the associated component. I mean if you create the store in the initComponent function this store is probably ghoing to stay around when you destroy the associated grid ...

Comment: Shouldn't the garbage collector take care of that? If i destroy the view that holds the reference to the store the store wouldn't be referenced anymore? I think it would be too much overhead to have multiple view and store classes just for having multiple views with different store parameters, isn't it?

Comment: I absolutely agree about defining multiple views /stores for this is not an option, and yes I guess the garbage collector will get rid of this store as there is anything referencing to it.

Comment: Already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368951/are-stores-created-in-the-initcomponent-function-memory-leaks-once-the-component

Comment: Thanks for the additional question. Will have a look at the answers.

Answer (score 3):

**The thing with the stores array of the controller** 
is, that it will override any `storeId` defined. After loading the store class the controller set the `storeId` by a namespace convention, create the store and create the getter method method by using the value as the `soreId`.

**Let me introduce option 4**

- Define one store for the view and require it in the view (you can also require it within the controller, just use the `requires` array).
- Choose valid [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-itemId)'s for the views and valid [storeId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-storeId)'s for your store that should depend on the `itemId` of the view (set it when creating the view!).
- Within the `initComponent` create the `storeId` and lookup the store in the StoreManager. If it not exist create it and supply a Customer config and the `storeId`.

If you need to destroy the view and the store each time take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368951/are-stores-created-in-the-initcomponent-function-memory-leaks-once-the-component/27374842#27374842)

Demo initComponent

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this,
        storeId = me.storeId + me.itemId;
    me.store = Ext.StoreManager.lookup(storeId);
    if(me.store === null)
        me.store = Ext.create('App.data.CustomViewStore',Ext.apply({storeId: storeId},me.storeCfg || {}));
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

**Note:** If you load the view with the `views` array you will end up with a getter that may not give you the view you expected. You may use the requires array of the controller here, too. If you want to use getter simply create your own one by using the [refs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs) config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can't see the "big" difference to my option 2. Is it just about the storeId and Ext.StoreManager or am i missing something?

Comment: @Werzi2001 No, it is not a big difference. But it is a difference which make sense! The thing is that you can still define your store at is own and don't pollute your views `initComponent` method with it.