# Are Stores created in the initComponent function memory leaks once the component is destroyed or will these stores be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, extjs, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, extjs4

This is a question that surged from this other one:

[Best practice to have the same view and store multiple times in ExtJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333787/best-practice-to-have-the-same-view-with-different-store-parameters-in-extjs-4)

So in a scenario where stores are created in the initComponent function of a grid.

**Should I override onDestroy of the grid to also destroy the store ?**

**Or these stores would be garbage collected because simply there are no references to them?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. No, the store will still exist after destroying the Grid
> 2. No, you will not need to override the destroy method of the grid

You can force the store to destroy itself by setting it's `autoDestroy` flag to `true` [API-Link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-autoDestroy)

> ```
> autoDestroy : Boolean
> ```
>
> When a Store is used by only one DataView, and should only exist for
>   the lifetime of that view, then configure the autoDestroy flag as
>   true. This causes the destruction of the view to trigger the
>   destruction of its Store.
>
> ```
> Defaults to: false
> ```

See this [working demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/eo9) for the effect of `autoDestroy` on a store that is used by a grid (close the grids in the demo)

**Additional info:**

1. Always use a [storeId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-storeId)
2. Use the [StoreManager](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager) to lookup the existence of a store